# Range filter for a Tableau dimension

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to get a Dimension's (`Block`) filter to display as a range, like the filter for a Measure (`CNTD(APN)`)?:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranges are available for Continuous values. The blue pill for Block indicates they are discrete values. Green would indicate continuous. Right-click (or use the dropdown arrow) and switch it from Discrete to Continous. The pill will change to green and then allow a range.

Comment: Is there a way to get the sliders to change in increments of 100?

Comment: Make sure Block is a number type on your dimensions shelf. Then edit the filter (click the dropdown to the right of the title) and you should have options to allow for a slider with ranges. Going off memory at the moment so I may be mistaken.